# Telegram is automatically turning off in windows 10?

Tags: windows, background

Telegram is automatically turning off in windows 10 when in background. What should I do?
It worked perfectly till yesterday. And I don't remember I changed any settings or something.

Comment: Turning off? Do you mean not refreshing with new messages? Force closing?

Comment: And what, exactly, is Telegram? The official [Telegram](https://www.telegram.org) desktop client? Or something different?

Comment: Hi, can you please provide more specific information about your issue? Is it happened to Telegram Desktop for Windows 10?